# Give argument to action on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do I give an argument to my action of a controller.

I have an action named action and a controller named controller. I want to give an argument to the action when I go to

http://localhost:3000/controller/action/argument1 or to

http://localhost:3000/controller/action/argument2

How do I know, which argument was actually passed in my action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is the best place to start. Right up the very top, there's an example of passing in a parameter (in this case, id):

```
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show'
```

(the line above would go in your `routes.rb` file). The `id` param would then be available in your controller, in `params[:id]`

So in your case, you'd have a line in your `routes.rb` with something like:

```
get '/controller/action/:argument', to: 'controller#action'
```

And then you could refer to your argument in your controller as `params[:argument]`